# How to get input in Python 2.7?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cygwin

First, let me share my simple code;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

print ("test")

var = raw_input("Enter your words: ")
print ("Your words: "), var
```

What I expect when I run this code is that first, "test" text will appear on the screen, then "Enter your words: " text will appear and wait for my input. After I enter my input, it will also show my input on the screen with the last print command.

However, what I get when I run this code is that it waits for an input first, then after I give my input value, It shows all values respectively. It writes "test" first, then my input value on the screen.

Can you help me for solving this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a print statement from python 3+ with python 2+.

According to the [What's new in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html), you can see that [the print method is now a function](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function).

```
Old: print "The answer is", 2*2
New: print("The answer is", 2*2)

Old: print x,           # Trailing comma suppresses newline
New: print(x, end=" ")  # Appends a space instead of a newline

Old: print              # Prints a newline
New: print()            # You must call the function!

Old: print >>sys.stderr, "fatal error"
New: print("fatal error", file=sys.stderr)

Old: print (x, y)       # prints repr((x, y))
New: print((x, y))      # Not the same as print(x, y)!
```

**Python 2+:**

```
print "test"
```

**Python 3+:**

```
print("test")
```

**Fixed Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

print "test"

var = raw_input("Enter your words: ")
print "Your words: ", var
```

**Output of the fixed code:**

> anon@anon-pc:~/Desktop$ python test.py
>
> test
>
> Enter your words: itsWorking
>
> Your words:  itsWorking
>
> anon@anon-pc:~/Desktop$

Comment: I tried the fixed code but it still waits for an input. What actually it should do is that first, it should print "test", then it should wait for an input with the string "Enter your words: ". @Dot_Py

Comment: I am using Cygwin64 terminal on windows 10. Could my problem be related with it?

Comment: Maybe... why don't you install python or a pack of packages like anaconda (installable) or winpython (portable version)? With winpython, if you don't like it, you could just delete it's folder and it's done. :D